# purpose of skeleton directory

Tags: python, import, module

I'm just getting into programming; I've made some simple scripts and am hoping to learn how to do things with them. I have a question about where these files "live" on my computer, and if that's important. Let's say I have a script in the directory `users/me/desktop/project/skeleton/` called `webproject.py`. In the `skeleton/` directory I also have `tests/`; does `tests/` have to be in `skeleton/` or can it be in some random place like my `desktop/`?

Further, if one of my scripts imports a module that I've created, does it matter where that's located? If I make a script with a function that outputs the nth fibonacci number, and save it on my desktop, can my `webproject.py` script from `users/me/desktop/project/skeleton/` import it?

Any links/resources would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It of course matters where you place your files.  There sure is more than one directory called "tests", so your Python interpreter cannot guess what "tests" directory it should pick.  There is no magic in your computer, I am sorry. ;)  But there is something called "Python path".  All modules which are saved in a directory specified in the Python path can be `import`ed from anywhere. To use `webproject.py` from "project/skeleton/" you would have to include "project/skeleton/" in your Python path or make it a package.

There is [a nice chapter](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) in the official Python tutorial about modules. :)